# Core data database design issues

Tags: ios, database-design, core-data

I want to create a core data model to store user input questions and then entries for those questions.

The questions will be 1 of 3 types. (1-10, Yes No or a number of specific units). So users will go into the app, click "add question" and will be shown a form where they will input the **question title** choose the **question type** (Yes/No, Scale 1-10 or Specific Units) - and if they choose specific units they have to put in those units eg: centimetres, millimetres, litres etc...

There will be multiple entries to these questions mapped over a period of time. IE: Users may put in the questions "How tall is your tomato plant? - specific units - CMs" and "How red are your tomatos? - scale 1-10" and will go back into the app time and again to map out the progress over time.

My question is about database design for this. How would I set this up in my core data?

At the moment I have this:

[image]

Now, I'm stuck! I don't quite know how to account for the fact that questions have different types, and therefore the entries will be different.

Plus I need to account for questions where units may be required. These are the questions that will just be a number.

So I'm thinking I probably need different question entites. Something like having a Questions entity and the specific questions as sub-entites - but I'm not sure how to do this, and not sure how to then record the entries made to those questions!

Thank you for looking, and for helping if you can. :)

Comment: Make the question entity an abstract entity and and new entities with the abstract entity as parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no correct way to design it, and there are indeed many different ways to design a solution.

As @dasdom suggested, you could remove the `value` from the `Entry` entity description, and make `Entry` abstract.  Create three subclasses of `Entry` (`BooleanAnswer`, `RankedAnswer`, and `ValueAnswer` for example).  The `ValueAnswer` would have a `decimalValue` and `units`, the others similar related values.

Also, FYI on naming conventions:

- Entities: upper case, singular: `Question` and `Entry` (though i'd name it `Answer`)
- Attributes/Relationships: lower case: `questionText`, `type`, `entries`, `value`, `questions` ('forQuestion' and 'forEntity' are redundant, being the relationship is defined on each of those)

Another option is to have `Entity` have `units`, `boolValue`, `rankValue`, and `decimalValue` but only use the attribute that's relevant.  That's not an elegant solution, imho.

Comment: The nonelegqnt solution is likely to perform much better , you should not consider elegance when designing databases. YOu will usually get the worst solution from a data perspective. EAV tables ar eone of the worst designs you can have but they appear to some people to be elegant.

Comment: @HLGEM  Whether, when, and how to optimize data models and implementations is beyond the scope of the question.  And I totally concede that some people totally disagree with 'my humble opinion' of elegance.  And there *are* cases where I would 'sparse matrix' a solution. Indeed, I believe there is a way to hint to core data (there used to be in EOF) to implement the storage of a 'class cluster' just that way.  When 'object modeling', i don't think you should design that way - when 'database designing' it's absolutely valid.

Comment: What I object to  is the fallacy of trying to inject elegance into database design. It is inappropraite at best and actively harmful at worst. I would fire anyone who tried to make an elegant database design at the expense of what is important in db design: data integrity, performance, and security.

Comment: I did it the inelegant way and it works perfectly. Thank you very much.